# is there any crittercism jenkins plugin available for android

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, crittercism

Some of you guys might be aware that automatically upload iOS symbolication file(dSYM) to crittercism server from jenkins is possible using [Crittercism dSYM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Crittercism+dSYM+Plugin) .

I am looking for similar plugin which can upload android proGuard mapping file ("mapping.txt") to crittercism directly from jenkins.

those who have some relevant idea, please share your thought.

Comment: Have you tried using the existing plugin, but placing your mapping.txt in the dSYM field?

Comment: yes . n as expected. it shows error : 400, invalid dSYM file

Comment: Ok. It was worth a try, as the HockeyApp plugin works for Android, even although the API has iOS-named parameters. You could probably modify the plugin yourself relatively easily to work with both OS types.

Comment: well i can live without this feature. we will need to upload it once in a while, most likely at the time of uploading apk marketplace .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now upload mapping.txt files automatically using the APIs built specifically for Android and Android NDK.

More information can be found here: http://docs.crittercism.com/android/android.html#uploading-the-mapping-txt-file

As a note, just found this question again, but this has been out for a while now.

Comment: Sounds awesome. thank you for your answer. however i am away from crittercism now a days . accepting this as answer without verifying.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this to crittercism support group as well .

First of all i wold like to appreciate their prompt response .

As per that mail, automatic upload option for Android symbolication is not supported yet and is something they want to target in upcoming release .

lets hear the story from the horse's mouth :

---

> Date: Tue, 28 May 2013 18:13:09 +0000 From: support@crittercism.com
>   To: XXX@XXX.com Subject: Re: Is there any API to
>   upload "mapping.txt" for android app
>
> Hi Shailendra,
>
> Good to hear from you. Sorry for the delay in responding, yesterday
>   was a holiday here for us, and I only saw your message this morning.
>
> Regarding the automatic upload of the mapping.txt files, I'm afraid
>   this isn't currently possible. We have been planning this feature for
>   several sprints, but it has not been included yet.
>
> I'll go ahead and add your comments to the feature request which we
>   have been working on. This week I'll be pushing to get this feature
>   scheduled, but it may take some time before it is fully ready.
>
> Would you like us to let you know when it comes out?
>
> Are there any other features which would make using Crittercism a
>   better experience for you?
>
> Thanks for your feedback!
>
> Jeremiah
>
> On May 28, 2013 at 5:31 p.m. Shailendra Rajawat
>    wrote:
>
> ```
> Waiting for your response .
> Regards,
> Shailendra
>
> On May 27, 2013 at 1:57 p.m. Shailendra Rajawat wrote:
>
>     Hi,
>     Hope you are doing great.
>     i am using cttercism for android and i want to automate the process of uploading proGuard mapping file "mapping.txt" .
>     i am using jenkins -CI and will be delighted if somehow jenkins can send mapping.txt to crittercism server automatically. its
> ```
>
> possible only if you provide such kind of API .
>           i came to know that such api is available for iOS dSYM file uploading .
>           waiting for your response.
>
> ```
>     Regards,
>     Shailendra
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Following the crittercism [doc](http://docs.crittercism.com/android/android.html#uploading-the-mapping-txt-file) Eddie mentioned you could wrap the curl command in a gradle task.  If you set your new task to the assembleRelease finalizeBy then a mapping file will upload every time a release apk is built.  Of course you will need to define those variables yourself.

```
task uploadMapping(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'assembleRelease') {

    commandLine 'curl',
            "https://app.crittercism.com/api_beta/proguard/$critterAppId",
            '-F', 'proguard=@build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt',
            '-F', "app_version=$appVersionName-$appVersionCode",
            '-F', "key=$critterKey"
}
assembleRelease.finalizedBy uploadMapping
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is working fine.(local build and jenkins build)

for me, only working when build is from jenkins

make sure your APPID, APPKEY, and path(release_jenkins.... normally release)

**build.gradle (app)** (add at the end)

```
task uploadPro << {
    logger.error("Uploading mapping.txt file to crittercism")
    String temp = projectDir;
    temp = temp.replace("\\", "/");
    String[] cmd = ["curl", "-k", "https://app.crittercism.com/api_beta/proguard/AppIDSting",
                 "-F", "proguard=@" + temp + "/build/outputs/mapping/release_jenkins/mapping.txt",
                 "-F", "app_version=" + VERSION_NAME + '-' + VERSION_CODE,
                 "-F", "key=API_KEY"]
    logger.error("CMD : " + cmd)
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    Process process = builder.start();
    process.waitFor()
    println process.err.text
    println process.text
    }

gradle.buildFinished {
    //check your build type. I am not sure it's the best way to do it.
    logger.error("JSC : 이름 ! - " + gradle.startParameter.taskNames);
    if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("assembleRelease_jenkins")) {
        logger.error("JSC : 올리기 시작 ! - " + gradle.startParameter.taskNames);
        tasks.uploadPro.execute()
    } else {
        logger.error("JSC : PASS")
    }
}
```

[jenkins console output capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTS3C.png)

Comment: If you have trouble, I made git project   [link](https://github.com/SinsangMarket/CrittercismMappingTXT)